# Images broken after site migration

Tags: wordpress, image, utf-8, migrating

I have a friend that has a wordpress/woocommerce website.

It's in danish, and he has uploaded ALLOT of images (hundreds) with danish filenames (that is with æøå in them) ...

Now that I helped him migrate to a new domain ... all the images with those characters in them, break ...

[image in medialibary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHMp3.png)

[image open in a new tab 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amA9m.png)

That is, when I right click the image and copy the path it looks like this: 
wp-content/uploads/2016/03/sm%C3%A5b%C3%B8rn-no.9.jpg

if I open it in a new tab it have the right path: 
wp-content/uploads/2016/03/småbørn-no.9.jpg

but, it gives me a 404 ...

I figure I need help changing all the filenames automatically if that can in any way be done? ...

He is really pressing me about it, so hope someone can help me fast...

I have allready tried allot of plugins, but none of them have worked.. 
Etc. "Clean Image Filenames" only seams to work if you install the plugin before you ever upload any files (we should have done that)...

Thank so much for your help ...

Comment: I have to add that the files are there on the ftp, with the original file names...

Comment: I had a similar issue with a client website. Sorry but you will need to replace manually all images with special characters in names, one by one. I have used for that 2 plugins to help: **Clean Image Filenames** plugin and **Enable Media Replace** plugin.

Comment: Well the images are there intact on the ftp... are you sure there is nothing to do? 

My friend will freak, it's about 700 images (weeks of work to replace them) 


How did you use the two plugins to make it easier?

Comment: Yes it's a long process… Enable Media Replace => replace medias in media library list. Clean Image Filenames just clean out all special characters from dirty file names when uploading to media library. Together you will replace easily only media files with dirty names converted to clean names. So the new files will have clean names on the file server and on database too.

Comment: I still have access to the old site where it works ... 
If that would be any help